# Salesforce Integration with C# with SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, c#, excel

I have a requirement to enable SSO for a excel add-in application to salesforce. Currently we are using sfdc user name and password while connecting to salesforce from excel add-in. Now the requirement is we should not prompt for username and password, instead user should be authenticated using SSO. Please share your ideas if anyone has done the same requirement as I am new to C# :)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

High-Level Steps to Configure SSO, In your case first you have to **Setup Salesforce as a SAML Identity Provider(IdP)** then add SAML support in your .NET Application to do the SSO.

Follow this link to get the details of the above mentioned steps. https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Configuring-SAML-SSO-to-Custom-.Net-Application